# What is wrong with my binary search python code?

Tags: python, binary-search

Exercise 1: “Search and Destroy... But Nicer”

As a web developer working for a retail store, your job is to create a website where the store can sell its products online. Your first task is to create a search option for the customers, so they can easily find specific items they are looking for in your shop.

Each item in your shop corresponds to a specific 4-digit code. Starting with a pre-defined list, perform both searching algorithms (Linear and Binary) to find your items. Ask the user to input an item (using a number code) and your program should output if the code was able to find your item in the list.

The predefined list should contain the following values in this order:
4599, 3102, 1024, 9980, 2912, 1569, 4205, 9811, 1001, 7638, 4733, 1989, 5555, 5000, 3861

So this is my code for binary.

```
def binary_search(item_list,code):
  start = 0
  end = len(item_list)-1
  if start >= end: #check base case
    mid = int((start + end) / 2)
    if item_list[mid] == code:
      return mid
    if item_list[mid] > code:
      end = mid + 1
    if item_list[mid] < code:
      start = mid - 1
  else:
    return -1
```

I tried running it but it will not really determine. It will just always say they found it for every numbers I enter even though it's not on the list. I actually tried anything but the results would be either found for all numbers or not found for all numbers. For more context, this is my entire code:

```
print ("WELCOME TO OUR SHOP")
print ("-------------------")
# Linear search function
def linear_search(code, item_list):
  for i in range(len(item_list)):
    if item_list[i] == code:
      return True
  return False

# Binary search function
def binary_search(item_list,code):
  start = 0
  end = len(item_list)-1
  if start >= end: #check base case
    mid = int((start + end) / 2)
    if item_list[mid] == code:
      return mid
    elif item_list[mid] > code:
      end = mid + 1
    else:
      start = mid - 1
  else:
    return -1

# Predefined list of items
item_list = [4599, 3102, 1024, 9980, 2912, 1569, 4205, 9811, 1001, 7638, 4733, 1989, 5555, 5000, 3861]

#ask user to input an item code
code = int(input("Find an item: \n"))

# Use linear search to find the item
result = linear_search(code, item_list)

print("\nLinear Search")
print("searching...\n")
if result:
  print("The Item",code,"was found.")
else:
  print("The Item",code,"was not found.")

# Use binary search to find the item
result = binary_search(item_list, code)

print("\nBinary Search")
print("searching...\n")
if result:
  print("The Item",code,"was found.")
else:
  print("The Item",code,"was not found.")
```

Comment: Binary search only works on a sorted list.

Comment: Also, presumably you meant to have some sort of loop inside the function...

Comment: Instead of `mid = int((start + end) / 2)` you can just say `mid = (start+end)//2`

Comment: if start <= end: ? Your binary search will return -1 given by else statement  as end will always be >=0.

Comment: Binary search basic point is to convert in sorted order ascending or descending...!